# No further optimization for this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, relational-database

I have some tables I want to join, but it cannot take dozens of seconds.

I want to go from this query that takes ~1s

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM business_group bg WHERE bg.group_id=1040
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
| 1229380  |
+----------+
1 row in set
Time: 1.173s
```

to this joined query that is taking ~50s

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM business b
                INNER JOIN business_group bg ON b.id=bg.business_id
                WHERE bg.group_id=1040
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
| 1229380  |
+----------+
1 row in set
Time: 51.346s
```

Why does it take that long if the only thing it does differently is to join on the primary key of the `business` table (`business.id`)?

Besides this primary key index, I also have this one `(group_id, business_id)` on `business_group` (with `(business_id, group_id)` it took even longer).

Following is the execution plan:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+----------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                           | key                         | key_len | ref                  | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+----------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | bg    | <null>     | ref    | FKo2q0jurx07ein31bgmfvuk8gf,idx_bg_group_id_business_id | idx_bg_group_id_business_id | 9       | const                | 2654528 | 100.0    | Using index              |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | b     | <null>     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                 | PRIMARY                     | 4       | database.bg.group_id | 1       | 100.0    | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+----------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
```

Is it possible to optimize the second query so it takes less time?

`business` table is ~45M rows while `business_group` is ~60M rows.

Comment: Actually `(group_id, business_id)` is a good choice, and you might also want to experiment with `(business_id, group_id)`.  How large are these tables?

Comment: 45M and 60M is a lot of data.  I'm not surprised by your current running times.

Comment: You could look into using a materialized view perhaps.  Your current query and indexing approach already looks pretty optimal to me.

Comment: I need the COUNT for pagination reasons, so it cannot take ~50s. Is there a better way to get this COUNT?

Comment: Because for each of the 45M records, you need to do a lookup against a second table which has 60M records.  That takes time.  You might want to look into using a hash index, which can have faster lookup times than with the default B tree.

Comment: If a true count is not needed as a “next” can be done without forcing a full materialization to count .. However, I suspect that addition of an ORDER BY / LIMIT .. OFFSET will itself be problematic, regardless of the first attempt to obtain a count.

Comment: Anyway, use EXPLAIN (FORMAT=TREE) to get a more readable plan display to show where the time goes and what kinds of joins are used. The standard output is a PITA to show on SO. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/hash-joins.html gives an example, as will the specific EXPLAIN documentation. The link above also discusses and links different join approaches.

Comment: Are you really doing just a `COUNT(*)` with that `JOIN`?  Or is your "real" query more involved?  In that case, let's see it; there may be other techniques to speed it up that we can't discuss in this watered down example.

Comment: `(group_id, business_id)` is obviously better, since it works on `WHERE` first, before getting to `ON`.

Comment: "Count for pagination" -- Estimated it, do not calculate such a big count.  Anyway what robot, let alone human, has the patience to page through 1.2M items?  Find another approach to letting users see more than the first few hundred rows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this as someone who does a lot of indexing setups on SQL Server rather than MySQL. It is too long as a comment, and is based on what I believe are fundamentals, so hopefully it will help.

**Why?**

Firstly - why does it take so long for the second query to run? The answer is that it needs to do a *lot* more work in the second one

To demonstrate, imagine the only non-clustered index you have is on `business_group` for `group_id`.

You run the first query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM business_group bg WHERE bg.group_id=1040`.

- All the engine needs to do is to seek to the appropriate spot in the index (where group_id = 1040), then read/count rows from the index (which is just a series of ints) until it changes - because the non-clustered index is sorted by that column.
- Note if you had a second field in the non-clustered index (e.g., `group_id, business_id`), it would be almost as fast because it's still sorted on group_id first. However, it will be a slightly larger read as each row is 2x the size of the single-column version (but would still be very small).

Imagine you then run a slightly different query, counting `business_id` instead of * e.g., `SELECT COUNT(business_id) FROM business_group bg WHERE bg.group_id=1040`.

- Assuming `business_id` is not the PK (and is not in the non-clustered index), then for every row it finds in the index, it then needs to go back and read the business_id from the table check it's not null (either in some sort of loop/reference, or read the whole table - I'm not 100% on how MySQL deals with these). However, it is a lot more work than above.
- If `business_id` was in the index (as above, for `group_id, business_id`), then it could read that data straight from the index and not need to refer back to the original table - which is good.

Now add the join (your second query) `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM business b INNER JOIN business_group bg ON b.id=bg.business_id WHERE bg.group_id=1040`. The engine needs to

- Get each business_id as above
- Potentially sort the business IDs to help with the join
- Join it to the business table (to ensure it has a valid row in the business table)
- ... and to do so, it may need to read all the row's data in the business table

**Suggestions #1 - Avoid going to the business table**

If you set up foreign keys to ensure that `business_id` in `business_group` is valid - then do you need to run the version with the join? Just run the first version.

**Suggestion #2 - Indexes**

If this was SQL Server and you needed that second query to run as fast as possible, I would set up two non-clustered indexes

1. NONCLUSTERED INDEX ... ON business_group (group_id, business_id)
2. NONCLUSTERED INDEX ... ON business (id)

The first means the engine can seek directly to the specific `group_id`, and then get a *sorted list* of `business_id`.

The second provides a sorted list of `id` (business_id) from the business table. As it has the same sort as the the results from the first index, it means the join is a lot less work.

However, the second one is controversial - many people would say 'no' to this as it overlaps your PK (or, more specifically, clustered index). It would also be sorted the same way. However, at least in SQL Server, this would include all the other data about the businesses e.g., the business name, address, etc. So to read the list of IDs from business, you'd also need to read the rest of the data - taking a lot more time.

However, if you put a non-clustered index just on ID, it will be a very narrow index (just the IDs) and therefore the amount of data to be read would be much less - and therefore often a lot faster.

Note though, that this is not as fast as if you could avoid doing the join altogether (e.g., Suggestion #1 above).